# Create IJavaProject from directory path

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I need to create a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject` instance from a given directory path to the java project. I only seem to find about creating new java projects dynamically or creating an `IJavaProject` from a given `IProject` (`org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject`) in the realm of eclipse plug-in development like so `JavaCore.create(iProjectInstance)`.
How would I go about creating an IJavaProject from a given java project located at a given path? So I would be looking for something like this:

```
IJavaProject myJavaProject = Utility.getJavaProjectFromPath("C:/workspace/MyJavaProject");
```

EDIT:
I have an ecplise plugin project and already can retrieve a IJavaProject via a IProject object I get from selecting a given project in the eclipse instance the plugin runs it. But I want to write a JUnit test for it and therefore need to somehow create the IJavaProject object just from a given path where a test project is located.

Comment: You have to do this in an Eclipse plugin. This API is not available in a plain Java program.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about it doing it in an eclipse plugin? My project actually is an eclipse plugin, but I cannot seem to find anything on how to do it there either.

Comment: It has to be a project in the current workspace and use `IProject`.

Comment: I think it was my fault for not formulating my current situation correctly then: I actually have an eclipse plugin project and already can get the Java Project from a selected item in the explorer. But I want to write a JUnit test for my plugin which works on a given java project and not always and only manually test it while booting up a runtime eclipse application and actually click on it etc.
So this is why I want to create a IJavaProject-object programmatically from a given path, to let a JUnit test run on it.

Is there any way to do this?